# Is it officially proven that the Collatz sequences can't go to infinity?

Tags: soft-question, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

> Did the mathematician Jeffrey Lagarias prove that [in his work](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228386392_The_3x_1_Problem_An_Overview) the Collatz sequences could not go to infinity (divergent trajectory), that only cyclicity can exist?

I don't have enough mathematics to analyze the book myself. But I think it was implied in the book.

Comment: What makes you think that way?

Comment: No, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489225/collatz-type-problems-with-known-divergent-trajectories), which is from $2015$, so later than the survey article by Lagarias. See the comment by Gottfried Helms. If you search this site you will find more posts about it, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942741/the-periodic-collatz-conjecture?rq=1), etc.

Comment: From mathworld: "Conway proved that the original Collatz problem has no nontrivial cycles of length $< 400$. Lagarias ($1985$) showed that there are no nontrivial cycles with length $< 275000$". This result does not mean there might be non-trivial cycles of length with bigger periodicity than these. Not that this has anything to do with your question though.

Answer (score 1):

That has not yet been proven.

*(And even there was no viable path found yet to do a proof in finite time)*